# 'ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key' when trying to filter data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble selecting certain rows in my dataset.

Given this data:

```
ticker  date    Unnamed: 0  filing_date currency_symbol totalassets intangibleassets    earningassets   othercurrentassets  totalliab   totalstockholderequity  deferredlongtermliab    othercurrentliab    commonstock retainedearnings    otherliab   goodwill    otherassets cash    totalcurrentliabilities shorttermdebt   shortlongtermdebt   shortlongtermdebttotal  otherstockholderequity  propertyplantequipment  totalcurrentassets  longterminvestments nettangibleassets   shortterminvestments    netreceivables  longtermdebt    inventory   accountspayable totalpermanentequity    noncontrollinginterestinconsolidatedentity  temporaryequityredeemablenoncontrollinginterests    accumulatedothercomprehensiveincome additionalpaidincapital commonstocktotalequity  preferredstocktotalequity   ... changereceivables   cashflowsotheroperating exchangeratechanges cashandcashequivalentschanges   changeinworkingcapital  othernoncashitems   freecashflow    ticker  Unnamed: 0  code    type    name    exchange    currencycode    currencyname    currencysymbol  countryname countryiso  isin    cusip   cik employeridnumber    fiscalyearend   ipodate internationaldomestic   sector  industry    gicsector   gicgroup    gicindustry gicsubindustry  homecategory    isdelisted  description address phone   weburl  logourl fulltimeemployees   updatedat
0   0G3T.LSE    2017-12-31  61956.0 NaN SEK NaN NaN NaN 92744000.0  NaN NaN NaN 185417000.0 1192000.0   NaN NaN NaN 2.240000e+05    NaN 2.489530e+08    NaN NaN NaN 12620000.0  6.670000e+06    2.669680e+08    NaN 2.490900e+07    NaN 5.795400e+07    NaN NaN 13767000.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN IVECF.US    0.0 IVECF   Common Stock    IVECF   PINK    USD US Dollar   $   USA US  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN False   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2020-07-18
1   0G3T.LSE    2018-12-31  61942.0 NaN SEK NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 123360000.0 1194000.0   7.619100e+07    -1.000000e+03   NaN 1.110000e+05    NaN 2.260690e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.036500e+07    2.900550e+08    NaN 8.068200e+07    NaN 9.035700e+07    NaN NaN 14154000.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NSS.US  1.0 NSS Common Stock    NuStar Logistics L.P. SB NT FX/FL 43    NYSE    USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US67059T2042    67059T204   1110805.0   NaN December    2013-01-29  NaN Other   Other   NaN NaN NaN NaN ETD False   NuStar Logistics, L.P. engages in the terminal...   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 2021-10-20
2   0G3T.LSE    2019-12-31  106133.0    NaN SEK NaN NaN NaN 1000.0  NaN NaN NaN 170171000.0 1196000.0   1.899310e+08    NaN NaN 5.550000e+05    NaN 2.495870e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.359900e+07    4.140860e+08    NaN 1.831080e+08    NaN 1.422700e+08    NaN NaN 19381000.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN CMLLF.US    2.0 CMLLF   Common Stock    China Maple Leaf Educational Systems Limited    OTCGREY USD US Dollar   $   USA US  NaN NaN NaN NaN August  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN False   China Maple Leaf Educational Systems Limited, ...   Maple Leaf Educational Park, Dalian, China, 11...   86 40 0655 6877 http://www.mapleleaf.cn NaN 6623.0  2021-10-20
3   0G3T.LSE    2020-12-31  106132.0    NaN SEK NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 220934000.0 1203000.0   3.654220e+08    NaN NaN 7.730000e+05    NaN 3.060350e+08    NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.051090e+08    6.041580e+08    NaN 3.478740e+08    NaN 1.826840e+08    NaN NaN 16940000.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ZZZ.TO  3.0 ZZZ Common Stock    Sleep Country Canada Holdings Inc   TO  CAD Canadian Dollar C$  Canada  CA  CA83125J1049    NaN NaN NaN December    NaN NaN Consumer Cyclical   Specialty Retail    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Sleep Country Canada Holdings Inc., together w...   7920 Airport Road, Brampton, ON, Canada, L6T 4N8    289 748 0206    http://www.sleepcountry.ca  /img/logos/TO/ZZZ.png   1434.0  2021-03-17
4   0GO4.LSE    2017-12-31  106131.0    NaN SEK NaN NaN NaN 1000000.0   NaN NaN NaN 947000000.0 390000000.0 -4.876000e+09   2.786000e+09    NaN 1.277000e+09    NaN 4.514000e+09    NaN NaN NaN 284000000.0 2.557000e+09    7.432000e+09    NaN -6.290000e+09   NaN 1.977000e+09    NaN 1.375000e+09    353000000.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN YRI.TO  4.0 YRI Common Stock    Yamana Gold Inc TO  CAD Canadian Dollar C$  Canada  CA  CA98462Y1007    NaN NaN NaN December    NaN NaN Basic Materials Gold    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Yamana Gold Inc. operates as a precious metal ...   Royal Bank Plaza, Toronto, ON, Canada, M5J 2J3  416-815-0220    http://www.yamana.com   /img/logos/TO/YRI.png   0.0 2021-03-17
5 rows × 161 columns
```

When I try to select a specific ticker I get the following error:

```
df.loc[df['ticker'] == 'AAPL.US']
```

I get this error:

```
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    877 
    878             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 879             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    880 
    881     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1095 
   1096                 if hasattr(key, "ndim") and key.ndim > 1:
-> 1097                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
   1098 
   1099                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Answer (score 0):

df.loc requires a key and fieldname combination.   add a filter to the dataframe for the criteria you want

```
   df2=df.query("ticker=='AAPL.US'") 

   for key, row in df2.iterrows():
          df.loc[key,'mycol']='abc'
```

Comment: Try using df.query  then iterrate the rows